# How to change the Local settings manager of flash programatically

Tags: flash, apache-flex

i want to know whether its possible to change the local settings manager of flash programatically ?.
Earlier when the global settings manager was there i changed the settings by directly editing the .sol file? Will the same work now?

Comment: Change settings from Flash application? Enable camera, mic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work on the Settings Manager, and the last I knew, the control-panel-based version was supposed to edit the same .sol files as the old online version, in order to preserve interoperability with the old online Settings Manager.  So, yes, whatever you were doing before should continue to work.  However, I'm sure this could change in the future, as Adobe wants to eventually remove the online Settings Manager.

I'm sure you realize this, but it should never be possible to alter the .sol files for the Settings Manager from within a SWF from the Web.  I assume you must be talking about a script that runs on your local machine and directly edits the .sol files.

Comment: Yes..I am editing the sol file directly so that i can remove the camera and microphone prompts.I'll do some more research on this and see i can use the same way.